# Mysterious crash with NSString method rangeOfComposedCharacterSequenceAtIndex:

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsstring

My app uses several `UITextView`s, and we are getting a crash report from users that we are unable to reproduce.

The crash report doesn’t (seem to) contain any of our code, and crashes with an `NSInvalidArgumentException` in the `NSString` method `rangeOfComposedCharacterSequenceAtIndex:`, which isn't called directly by our code but seems to be called by the frameworks.

Here is the crash report:

```
0  CoreFoundation    __exceptionPreprocess + 130
1 libobjc.A.dylib    objc_exception_throw + 38
2  CoreFoundation    -[NSException initWithCoder:]
3  Foundation        -[NSString rangeOfComposedCharacterSequenceAtIndex:] + 88
4  UIKit             __74-[UITextInputController _validCaretPositionFromCharacterIndex:downstream:]_block_invoke + 328
5  UIFoundation      -[NSTextStorage coordinateReading:] + 36
6  UIKit             -[UITextInputController _validCaretPositionFromCharacterIndex:downstream:] + 218
7  UIKit             __52-[UITextInputController _characterPositionForPoint:]_block_invoke + 1112
8  UIFoundation      -[NSLayoutManager(TextLocking) coordinateAccess:] + 46
9  UIKit             -[UITextInputController _characterPositionForPoint:] + 224
10 UIKit             -[UITextSelection setSelectionWithFirstPoint:secondPoint:] + 56
11 UIKit             -[UITextInteractionAssistant(UITextInteractionAssistant_Internal) twoFingerRangedSelectGesture:] + 386
12 UIKit             _UIGestureRecognizerSendActions + 196
13 UIKit             -[UIGestureRecognizer _updateGestureWithEvent:buttonEvent:] + 1138
14 UIKit             ___UIGestureRecognizerUpdate_block_invoke + 48
15 UIKit             _UIGestureRecognizerRemoveObjectsFromArrayAndApplyBlocks + 218
16 UIKit             _UIGestureRecognizerUpdate + 282
17 CoreFoundation    __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 20
18 CoreFoundation    __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 284
19 CoreFoundation    __CFRunLoopRun + 730
20 CoreFoundation    CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 522
21 CoreFoundation    CFRunLoopRunInMode + 106
22 GraphicsServices  GSEventRunModal + 138
23 UIKit             UIApplicationMain + 1136
24 main.m line 16 
25 libdyld.dylib     start + 2
```

( https://gist.github.com/timarnold/6981caa6a1ee2b98c2fe )

Since I don’t know exactly what part of our code is causing the crash, I’m not sure what sample code would be helpful to post. I’m more interested in hearing if anyone has seen anything like this, or might have a suggestion about where or how to investigate this further.

## Update on 2013-11-21

I was able to reproduce this issue by doing the following:

- Add some text to my `UITextView`, including a trailing newline character (`\n`)
- Get my app to force the `UITextView` to resign first responder status
- Get my app to assign first responder status to my `UITextView`, and then tap to insert the cursor at the end of the string (around the location of the newline character)

after which the app crashed with the above report.

I attempted to create this in an empty Xcode project with just a stock `UITextView` and nothing else, and was unable to do so. It seems as though there's something going on in my app that conspires with `UITextView` to make this crash occur. Would love to know what, but the issue is solved for me in this project (as we are not interested in trailing newline characters, and can trim them, thus keeping crashes from occurring).

If someone can reproduce this in a sample project, would be great to file a radar if this is indeed a bug with `UITextView`.

Thanks to @wattson12 and @Johan Kool for responses leading to a solution.

Comment: the rangeOfComposedCharacterSequenceAtIndex might suggest that the user is entering an accented character, like the e in café

Comment: SPA: curious. Could you expand a bit (is there some documentation I should visit?) about why you think this? I tried entering accented characters and it doesn’t seem to be an issue.

Comment: just an off the cuff thought - the crash refers to composed characters and that includes accented strings as well as Chinese characters and the like - perhaps the user has mistakenly used a different language keyboard

Comment: @Tim Arnold, you'll probably need not just enter the text, but also play with text selection (`UITextSelection setSelectionWithFirstPoint:secondPoint:` is suspicious), and try to play with selection of the text that is not supposed to be selectable.

Comment: I am seeing this same crash. It seems to happen when you have a selection in one `UITextView` and then try to select something in another one (especially if the other one is located below the first one). No fix found just yet.

Comment: @TimArnold did you find a cause for this? I am seeing it when selecting a text view from outside the current text range. e.g. when I tap text the view becomes first responder, if I tap on white space outside current text I see the same crash as above

Comment: Have not yet found a solution. Both yours (@Wattson12) and @Johan Kool's solutions are helpful hints, but still not sure how to fix this.

Comment: I did some more looking and found that when it was crashing on become first responder there was a newline character at the end of my attributed string (though I think a plain NSString had same issue). I trimmed this and it seems fine

Comment: @wattson12 , I just made sure to trim newline characters from the string in my `UITextView` (`[self setText:[self.text stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet]]`), and I think that's fixed it (well, stopped the crashing. Still an issue if you need those newlines there)! Many thanks. Feel free to submit a solution and I will mark it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same problem today, I don't have an old device but would be interesting to see if this is different on < 7.0.3 since its very reproducible now and wasn't picked up before. I can't really explain the why, but here is what I noticed and the fix I used:

I saw that tapping on a text view was crashing when:

- I had a new line character at the end of the text, and
- I tapped somewhere outside the current text

My solution was to trim the newline from the end (I used a while loop to avoid removing any leading newline characters but stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet would be fine if thats not an issue)

Comment: also worth noting, our production app saw a huge increase in the frequency of this crash after releasing our app built against the iOS 7 SDK. Previously I think this crash existed but at a marginal level.

Comment: ok thanks. the app i'm seeing it on is iOS 7 only. I also wasn't able to recreate with a plain text view

Comment: We have found the same issue BUT it only appears in 7.0.x - not in iOS7.1. So I guess thats some kind of good news. (I´m having a hard time finding a good place too trim the text)

Answer (score 1):

Setting scrollEnabled to YES (default) fixed the crash for us.
We needed scrollEnabled to be NO for the UI. But an suboptimal UI is better then a crash so this category method enable it only for iOS versions below 7.1

```
- (void)enableScrollIfBuggyOSVersion {
    if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] compare:@"7.1" options:NSNumericSearch] == NSOrderedAscending) {
        [self setScrollEnabled:YES];
    } else {
        [self setScrollEnabled:NO];
    }
}
```